# Angular 6 - Unable to run external functions inside a particular function

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using ng-select for angular 6.

This is the HTML side of it:

```
        <ng-select [(ngModel)]="client.categoryId"
                   class="form-control"
                   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':clientCategoryId.errors && clientCategoryId.touched}"
                   #clientCategoryId="ngModel"
                   name="categoryId"
                   [addTag]="addTagNow"
                   required>
          <ng-option *ngFor="let cat of cats" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.title}}</ng-option>
        </ng-select>
```

And this is the typescript:

```
nCategory: Category = {
  title: ''
};

constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
}

addTagNow(name) {
  this.nCategory.title = name;
  this.categoriesCollection.add(this.nCategory);
}
```

This is the error:

`NgSelectComponent.html:91 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined
    at NgSelectComponent.push../src/app/components/edit-client/edit-client.component.ts.EditClientComponent.addTagNow [as addTag] (edit-client.component.ts:169)`

If I run the code outside of `AddTagNow` function it works perfectly fine.

How can I execute that code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are passing a reference to an object method, but the value of `this` is not being set. So you need to `bind(this)` to the function reference.

```ts
public addTagNowRef: (name)=>void;

constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
  this.addTagNowRef = this.addTagNow.bind(this);
}
```

Then use that property in the template.

```html
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="client.categoryId"
           class="form-control"
           [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':clientCategoryId.errors && clientCategoryId.touched}"
           #clientCategoryId="ngModel"
           name="categoryId"
           [addTag]="addTagNowRef"
           required>
  <ng-option *ngFor="let cat of cats" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.title}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Alternatively, you can use an arrow function to forward the call to the method.

```ts
public addTagNowRef: (name)=>void;

constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
  this.addTagNowRef = (name) => this.addTagNow(name);
}
```

The point here is that `this` must reference the component.

Comment: Thank you so much I would never, ever, ever, figure this out.

Comment: @Omar it's a function on the component. See the OPs example code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using `.bind(this)` :

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="client.categoryId"
           class="form-control"
           [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':clientCategoryId.errors && clientCategoryId.touched}"
           #clientCategoryId="ngModel"
           name="categoryId"
           [addTag]="addTagNow.bind(this)"
           required>
  <ng-option *ngFor="let cat of cats" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.title}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```